# Populate UICollectionView with asynchronous data?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, uicollectionview

I'm trying to populate a `UICollectionView` with data retrieved from an RSS feed, but the `UICollectionView` is `nil` when I need to reload it. Below is what I'm trying:

```
class ViewController: UITabBarController {

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://example.com/feed")!)
    var itemRSS: [RSSItem]? = nil

    @IBOutlet var currentCollection: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        RSSParser.parseFeedForRequest(request, callback: {
            (feed, error) -> Void in

            if let f = feed {
                self.itemRSS = f.items
                self.currentCollection.reloadData()
            }
        })

    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemRSS != nil ? itemRSS!.count : 0
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostViewCell
        let item = itemRSS?[indexPath.row]

        cell.titleLabel.text = item!.title

        return cell
    }
```

When it gets to `self.currentCollection.reloadData()` in `viewWillAppear`, it crashes saying that it is `nil`. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why would a tab bar controller have a link to a collection view anyway?

Comment: It's the root view. The default home tab has a collection in it. Is there another way I should do this?

Comment: You have a controller for the home tab, it should manage the collection...